# incorrect results while choosing largest number and squaring or cubing it

Tags: c, function, max

I want this program to choose the largest number and then based on user's input to square it or put it on cube. I know there's pow math function that can be used but I'm trying to play with functions as much as possible to get the hang of it. 
I already made one program that correctly shows me the largest number, and it works well. I didn't want to copy it so I wrote it from scratch and now I'm checking everything, it's almost same but shows wrong result even for MAX. What do I need to fix?

```
int max(int NUM1, int NUM2, int NUM3; )
{
    int NUM1, NUM2, NUM3;
    int X;
    if (NUM1 >= NUM2) {
        X = NUM1;
    } else {
        X = NUM2;
    }
    ;
    if (NUM3 >= X) {
        X = NUM3;
    }
    ;
    return X;
}

int square(int MAX)
{
    return MAX * MAX * MAX;
}

int cube(int MAX)
{
    return MAX * MAX;
}

int main()
{
    int NUM1, NUM2, NUM3, MAX;
    char A;
    printf("ENTER 3 NUMBERS: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &NUM1, &NUM2, &NUM3);
    MAX = max(NUM1, NUM2, NUM3);
    printf("LARGEST NUMBER: %d", MAX);
    printf("DO YOU WANT IT SQUARED OR CUBED? (S/C) ");
    scanf("%c", &A);
    if (A = "S") {
        printf("SQUARE: %d", square(MAX));
    } else {
        printf("CUBE: %d", cube(MAX));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you have the functions `square` and `cube` swapped.

Comment: Well at first glance, I see that your `square` function and your `cube` function are reversed. Also, what is the largest number you are trying to use? `int` has limits (depending on your system). 2^31 or 2^63 or possibly only 2^15 if you are on a 16 bit micro.

Comment: I tried compiling that program and got 4 errors. So I don't see how it *"shows wrong result even for MAX"* when it doesn't even compile.

Comment: After fixing the syntax errors, look up *variable shadowing* and compile with a healthy set of warnings enabled.

Comment: Note that names in all capitals (like MAX) are conventionally used to indicate macro names or constants (enumeration values) and occasionally for type names.  They are **not** used for regular variable names.  You would do well to adhere to convention; it makes your code easier to read.  It is not formally wrong; it is just unusual and sends the wrong hints to experienced readers.

Comment: "it's almost same but shows wrong result even for MAX" --> what was the input?  What was the wrong output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors and problems in your source. You would have found most of them if you had set the warning level to the max. Especially as a beginner you should do that, for example for GCC use the options `-Wall -Wextra` and if you like `-pedantic`.

1. There is no `#include <stdio.h>` which declares `printf()` and `scanf()`.
2. The parameter list of `max()` has a trailing semicolon that (at least) irritates GCC. Clang correctly moans about it. It has to be removed.
3. The function `max()` has both parameters **and** local variables `NUM1`, `NUM2`, and `NUM3`. The latter shadow the former, in other words you can't access the arguments. Additionally the values of the local variables are undefined.
4. There are empty statements (a single semicolon `;`) after the `if`s in `max()`. They don't do evil but disturb the casual reader.
5. The formulas of `square()` and `cube()` are swapped.
6. Add a newline character after your result output like this: `"LARGEST NUMBER: %d\n"` to separate output and following prompt visually.
7. `scanf()` is quite tricky to use and best avoided at all. This is true especially for reading single characters. I had to insert a blank before "%c" to skip the newline of the input line of the numbers.
8. The expression `(A = "S")` is an assignment of a pointer `const char *` to a character `char`. But you want to compare two characters so it has to be `(A == 'S')`. C differentiates between character literals and character array literals.
9. Choose lower case names for functions **and** parameters and variables. As others mention all upper case names are reserved for constants per convention.
10. Please adapt a good code style (there are lots of them if you ask your favorite search engine) and stick to it.

Comment: Up for the effort!

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. Stuff like 1, 4, 5 and 6 are just simple steps that could have easily been avoided if I got some sleep! I'm watching tutorial from FreeCodeCamp.org on YT and, while the guy's explaining very well, he doesn't combine everything we've learned so far. I learn by doing stuff on my own, combining everything into one program and tinkering it bit by bit. I'm always glad there are people like you guys that can help out!